# why Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(myGoogleApiClient) returns null

Tags: android

I am trying to add Gplus signin to my android app, but am having issues with `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson`. It always returns null on my device while testing the app. Here is how I am initializing googleclient and then trying to fetch user details from gplus.

**google client**

> mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
>                   .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
>                   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
>                   .addApi(Plus.API)
>                   .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
>                   .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
>                   .build();
>           //

**Connection & Disconnection**

> @Override
>       protected void onStart() {
>           super.onStart();
>           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
>       }
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onStop() {
>     super.onStop();
>     mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
> }
> ```

**fetching user details**

> Person currentPerson =
>   Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
>               if (currentPerson != null) {

Please note that all the below possible causes are checked already and they are OK.

1. internet connection
2. android permissions

Comment: Do you ever call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()`? If not, you probably can understand why you were returned null.

Comment: @MeetTitan YES of course!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i just found the solution, actually when the app is running in debug mode we have to create google-service.jason for SHA1 of debug.jks generated by android studio while building for debug mode.. no need to create your own keystone..copy SHA1 from Debug.keystore stored in /Users/"youruserfolder"/.android/debug.keystore and generate google-service.jason. Run the app and it works perfect :)